# What is the graft command in Python's MANIFEST.in file?

Tags: python, manifest, distutils, setup.py

I found a Python project with a `MANIFEST.in` file. I can guess at the meaning of much of it, but I am unclear on the meaning of the line:

```
graft tools
```

Comment: Git does not itself use anything named MANIFEST (with or without any suffix). The word *manifest* simply means "list" (see the noun definition at http://www.dictionary.com/browse/manifest) and many programs or projects have their own project-specific definition or use for such a list, but this depends on the specific project or program.

Comment: Python packages often have a `MANIFEST.in` file that is part of the package metadata.  This would all be easier to answer if you simply told us which repository you had cloned.

Comment: In short, the part I tripped over is that google 'found something' related to git, but I would have been better helped with suggestions, like here, that gave a clearer push to look at python packaging (or others) options. Specifically, 'not git' when 'manifest.in' is a search keyword. Thanks for the clarification. Now I know I can ignore the file (for now).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can see such a file in [`JoshData/pdfminer/MANIFEST.in`](https://github.com/JoshData/pdfminer/blob/64af48c7fd1aacdadccb2b3fb4ff52504728f831/MANIFEST.in) or [`openstack/deb-python-falcon/MANIFEST.in`](https://github.com/openstack-archive/deb-python-falcon/blob/cf011c7c8f002545bba807e5eef111912aec4c01/MANIFEST.in) for instance.

It is a python project which uses the [`MANIFEST.in` template](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template)

> A `MANIFEST.in` file can be added in a project to define the list of files to include in the distribution built by the `sdist` command.
>
> When `sdist` is run, it will look for the `MANIFEST.in` file and interpret it to generate the `MANIFEST` file that contains the list of files that will be included in the package.
>
> The manifest template has one command per line, where each command specifies a set of files to include or exclude from the source distribution.

Among the [`MANIFEST` commands](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#commands), you do have:

> ```
> graft dir
> ```
>
> include all files under dir

See the [Distutils tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial)

> The `MANIFEST.in` file took me a while to understand.
> It's the file that `distutils` uses to collect all the files in your project that will go into the final installer tarball (the file that gets distributed).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Also - thx to everyone for the comments added to the question. So, it seems not just new to git - but also 'unknowing' of python packaging.

Comment: @MichaelFelt: so, it is in fact a Python package?

Comment: @torek I would bet this git repo is indeed a python project.

Comment: Yes, it is a python project - cloud-init - FYI. Not really 'part of the question' - as I commented under question: google failed to stress that git may not be the most important keyword - clearly it seems to me now that 'manifest.in' was the vital keyword.